# How to install and run chrome without GUI on Centos 8?

Tags: centos, chrome, gui

How can I install and run chrome without GUI on Centos 8?
Please guide me.
Thank you.

Comment: **Why do you want to run the Chrome web browser without any GUI?** Please explain in several paragraphs of written English the actual usecase! Chrome is designed for non-blind human users using a screen, a keyboard, and a mouse (and some computers running CentOS don't even have any screens, for example web servers)

Comment: If you want to make HTTP requests from a shell script, consider using [curl(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html) or sometimes [wget(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html) and if you want to code a C program doing them, use [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this [Running Chrome headless](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)

As well the other alternative which is probably lighter and easier is running the text web browser lynx.
[Lynx homepage](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/current/index.html)